# Which values of $\alpha$ allows $p_k$ to be a probability mass function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am in front of this problem :

[image]

**The question is : for which values of alpha is it a probability mass function ?**

I suppose that I should use the property that :

$$ \sum\limits_{i} p_{i} = 1 $$

I don't know where to start or how to address this problem...

Comment: Hint: try to use $\sum_k = n(n+1)/2$

Comment: Could you explain where it comes from ?

Comment: $2S = (1 + 2 + \dots + n) + (n + n-1 + \dots + 1) = (n+1) + (n+1) + \dots + (n+1) = n(n+1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any positive integer $n$, $$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}2. $$ This can be shown by induction; it is trivially true for $n=1$, and assuming it is true for some $n\geqslant 1$, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k &= \sum_{k=1}^n k + (n+1)\\
&= \frac{n(n+1)}2 + (n+1)\\
&= \frac{n(n+1) +2(n+1)}2\\
&= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2,
\end{align}
hence showing it is true for $n+1$. Now from $$\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb P(X=k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha k = 1  $$
we immediately find that
$$
\alpha = \frac2{n(n+1)}.
$$